# How To Create a Horizontal Scrolling Menu starting from the centre?

Tags: css, scroll, menu

How to create a Horizontal Scrolling Menu starting from the centre as shown in the image below? I need to add scrolling to my page.

```
.vist {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you make a width of 200% of the screen viewport, that should do it

```
.vist {
     width: 200vw;
          }
```